# Extract value from XMLTYPE using PL/SQL, SQL, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, xmltype

I have a PL/SQL Function that returns a XMLTYPE and I would like to 
extract the value from the "result" tag, which is in this case is "0".
XMLTYPE is below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body><ns2:runSeriatimValuationResponse xmlns:ns2="http://seriatim.ipvfbm.pbgc.gov/">
<result>0</result>
</ns2:runSeriatimValuationResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Thanks for the help - Much appreciated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query return the value of result tag (`0` in this case):

```
SELECT XMLTYPE('<?xml version=''1.0'' encoding=''UTF-8''?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body><ns2:runSeriatimValuationResponse xmlns:ns2="http://seriatim.ipvfbm.pbgc.gov/">
<result>0</result>
</ns2:runSeriatimValuationResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>').EXTRACT('//result/text()').getStringVal() result
FROM dual;
```

In your case you don't need to convert to XMLTYPE, just apply `EXTRACT('//result/text()').getStringVal()` to the result of your function